# Using @AutoAnnotation in Kotlin, complaint method must be static

Tags: kotlin, annotations, dagger-2

In reference to https://google.github.io/dagger/multibindings.html, there's this code

```
@AutoAnnotation
static MyKey createMyKey(String name, Class<?> implementingClass, int[] thresholds) {
  return new AutoAnnotation_MyComponentTest_createMyKey(name, implementingClass, thresholds);
}
```

When converted to Kotlin, I use below

```
companion object {
    @AutoAnnotation
    @JvmStatic
    fun createMyKey(name: String, implementingClass: Class<*>, thresholds: IntArray): MyKey {
        return AutoAnnotation_MainActivity_createMyKey(name, implementingClass, thresholds)
    }
}
```

It still complaints

```
error: @AutoAnnotation method must be static
    public final com.elyeproj.daggermultibinding.MyKey createMyKey(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
                                                       ^
```

I tried both with and without `@JvmStatic` still not working. How to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me. Have the create key method as global function.

```
class HelloAutoAnnotations {
    fun execute() {
        println("HelloAutoAnnotations...")

        DaggerMyComponent.create().myMap().forEach(::println)
    }
}

@MapKey(unwrapValue = false)
private annotation class MyKey(val username: String, val password: String)

@Module
private class MyModule {
    @Provides
    @IntoMap
    @MyKey(username = "user1", password = "T0gether")
    fun providesUser(): String = "Rooney"

    @Provides
    @IntoMap
    @MyKey(username = "user2", password = "T0gether")
    fun provideUser(): String = "Doo"
}

@Component(modules = arrayOf(MyModule::class))
private interface MyComponent {
    fun myMap(): Map<MyKey, String>
}

@AutoAnnotation
private fun createMyKey(username: String, password: String): MyKey {
    return MyKeyCreator.createMyKey(username, password)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs:

> **Maps whose keys are not known at compile time**
>
> Map multibindings work only if your map’s keys are known at compile
>   time and can be expressed in an annotation. If your map’s keys don’t
>   fit in those constraints, then you cannot create a multibound map, but
>   you can work around that by using set multibindings to bind a set of
>   objects that you can then transform into a non-multibound map.

```
@Module
class MyModule {
  @Provides @IntoSet
  static Map.Entry<Foo, Bar> entryOne(...) {
    Foo key = ...;
    Bar value = ...;
    return new SimpleImmutableEntry(key, value);
  }

  @Provides @IntoSet
  static Map.Entry<Foo, Bar> entryTwo(...) {
    Foo key = ...;
    Bar value = ...;
    return new SimpleImmutableEntry(key, value);
  }
}

@Module
class MyMapModule {
  @Provides
  static Map<Foo, Bar> fooBarMap(Set<Map.Entry<Foo, Bar>> entries) {
    Map<Foo, Bar> fooBarMap = new LinkedHashMap<>(entries.size());
    for (Map.Entry<Foo, Bar> entry : entries) {
      fooBarMap.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    }
    return fooBarMap;
  }
}
```

So you should try this approach perhaps.